# Bootstrap navbar dropdown only should activate once clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want the navbar button hover drop-down effect to only activate once one of the navbar buttons is clicked. After that once clicked outside like body hover again should be disabled. At the moment hover is working where if I move the mouse around it activate (hence hover effect) but this can be annoying if user meant to not use navbar.

So normally when hovering the navbar, buttons shouldn't drop down any list. But once any of the navbar button is clicked, till you click out side, like the body all navbar buttons should be hovering like normally. I tried some jQuery but wasn't successful.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>BAPTIST</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./headerAndFooter.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">

      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav top-nav pull-right">
          <div class="dropdown">
            <li class="dropbtn"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> About Us</a></li>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
              <a href="#">Action</a>
              <a href="#">Another action</a>
              <a href="#">Something else here</a>
              <a href="#">Separated link</a>
              <a href="#">One more separated link</a>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="dropdown">
            <li class="dropbtn"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> Providers</a></li>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
              <a href="#">Action</a>
              <a href="#">Another action</a>
              <a href="#">Something else here</a>
              <a href="#">Separated link</a>
              <a href="#">One more separated link</a>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="dropdown">
            <li class="dropbtn"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> Payors</a></li>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
              <a href="#">Action</a>
              <a href="#">Another action</a>
              <a href="#">Something else here</a>
              <a href="#">Separated link</a>
              <a href="#">One more separated link</a>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="dropdown">
            <li class="dropbtn"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> Employers</a></li>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
              <a href="#">Action</a>
              <a href="#">Another action</a>
              <a href="#">Something else here</a>
              <a href="#">Separated link</a>
              <a href="#">One more separated link</a>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="dropdown">
            <li class="dropbtn"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> Patients</a></li>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
              <a href="#">Action</a>
              <a href="#">Another action</a>
              <a href="#">Something else here</a>
              <a href="#">Separated link</a>
              <a href="#">One more separated link</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do u have it in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble with getting your navbar to work without all the css you have, so I used the generic Bootstrap 3 navbar from the site to show you.

What the code below does is this:

- Anytime a link tag inside the nav is clicked, it will set the variable allowHover to true.
- Anytime the users mouse enters the div with class of "content", allowHover is set to false.

I believe the other two functions are self explanatory, but if they require explanation, let me know.

```
let allowHover = false

$('nav a').click(function() {
  allowHover = true
})

$('.content').mouseenter(function() {
  allowHover = false
})

$('ul.nav .dropdown').hover(function() {
    if(allowHover) 
      $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn('fast');
})

$('ul.nav .dropdown').mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut('fast');
})
```

Check out the [codepen](https://codepen.io/DZuz14/pen/dzeERR?editors=1010). Make sure you when you click a regular link in the nav, don't move your mouse outside of the navbar, or the dropdown won't work.

This is a close example to what you asked for, but I think its quite sufficient in getting you where you need to be to get your own rendition working.